# php echo into new html section / tag

Tags: php

I have this form code below, which works fine,  but im wondering if there is a shorter way to echo the result into a html paragraph.  For example i'd rather just say the function to echo without naming all the variables that make up the function (for example, as done in the p tag towards the end).

```
<?php
//variables and result
function bmi($height, $weight, $waist) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    $waist = floatval($waist);
    return round($weight / ($height * $waist),1);
}
?>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">

   <h4>ABI 1</h4>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" placeholder="height in meters or feet" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" placeholder="weight in kgs or lbs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="waist" name="waist" type="text" placeholder="waist in inches or cm" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['waist']) ? $_POST['waist'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>


   <?php
//handles if empty or 0 input
if (!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight']) && !
 empty($_POST['waist'])) : 

?>

 <p id="result">Your score is <?php echo bmi($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'],$_POST['waist']); 

endif;
?>
</p>  



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean you just want to call `bmi()` without parameters? And it should output the `<p id="result"...></p>` stuff too?

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal, meaning you have access to it inside of functions, without having to pass it in as a parameter. So you _could_ just remove the parameters from the function, call `echo bmi();` - and have the function _itself_ read the values directly from `$_POST`. […]

Comment: […] And the reason why you should rather _not_ do that, is that you would be needlessly limiting your function in the way it can be used. Not getting these values POSTed to the script on a different page, but read from the user’s record in the database, for example? Too bad, you’ll need a _second_ function for that now, because the one you had is “fixated” on getting its input data via `$_POST` now …

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes, i want to display on the client side what this code produces

<p id="result">Your score is <?php echo bmi($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight'],$_POST['waist']); 

endif;
?>
</p>


but by using code that is more succinct (without naming the variables etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
//variables and result
function bmi() {
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'height':
                $height = floatval($value);
                break;

            case 'weight':
                $weight = floatval($value);
                break;

            case 'waist':
                $waist = floatval($value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return round($weight / ($height * $waist),1);
}
```

and

```
<?php
//handles if empty or 0 input
if (!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight']) && !
 empty($_POST['waist'])) : 

?>

 <p id="result">Your score is <?php echo bmi(); 

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Maybe i should start another question for this, but i notice my if statement to catch empty input does not account for alphas being input.  How would this be dealt with using php?

Comment: You can allow only numbers in the input field `<input id="height" name="height" type="number" placeholder="height in meters or feet" value="">`